Why is almost everything gone after logging in after two months?
I occasionally work on a computer where Windows 10 is installed with two user profiles.
One user profile is for a user that works on the computer almost daily. This user did not experience any notable problems or data loss.
However, when I logged in today with my profile after approximately two months since the last login, almost anything seems, but not evertyhing, is gone. I am puzzled what happened.
Some observations:

My password still worked
The browser (Brave) opened with the tabs I had open when I last logged in
Thunderbird was still executable, yet the configuration (and of course saved eMails) is lost
The home directory (%USERPROFILE%) lost all directories I've created
The documents in the Document folder are still present
The path environment variable, which I changed, still contains the modifications

I am really not sure what happened here

Maybe someone set a group policy to delete user profile after a specified number of days? https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.UserProfiles::CleanupProfiles

Have you asked your system Administrator, what you describe, is not standard and likely specific to your corporate environment

@Ramhound, there is no system adminstrator, this is a bog installation at someone's home.

What is a “bog installation”?

A "factory (or default) installation" without any applied policy modifications.

One possibility: a Windows Update caused the issue. See if the old Thunderbird profile has been moved, or the Registry setting pointing to it is in WIndows.old https://www.howtogeek.com/223821/what-is-the-windows.old-folder-and-how-do-you-delete-it/ . You'll need to search the PC for your old Thunderbird Profile.

Most probably either a) an update caused the issue or b) an administrator or the other user did it.

Do you own this computer and are you the only user, or does someone else own it or have admin permissions on it? If the latter, you need to start by asking them. Next, have you checked to see whether you were logged in with a temporary profile? If you haven't check that.

@music2myear I am the only one with admin permissions on the computer

@DrMoishePippik on the entire c: drive, there is no windows.old directory nor a profiles.ini file

As far as I can tell, I am not logged in with a temporary profile (but I am not sure how to authoritatively verify).

Generally, go to C:\Users and look at the list of profiles and their Created or Modified date. You may find one named YourUsername.YourWorkspace or a numeric value and a recent Creation date which should contain copies of your profile data which would indicate an error in your main profile that needs to be fixed.
